# How to Change Font Size & Font-Family of Google Places Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm currently trying to adjust the CSS attributes of the Google Places Autocomplete in the Javascript API. In this link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete) I can see that the CSS classes are listed by Google.

[image: Autocomplete Font]

And I tried to edit the CSS directly in the HTML file:

```
<style>
    .pac-item-query { font-size: 12px; }
    .pac-item { font-size: 12px; }
    .pac-item-container { font-size: 12px; }
    .pac-item-matched { font-size: 12px; }
</style>
```

Though that does not seem to be working. I looked at other StackOverflow posts and was unable to find a solution that works.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<body id="page-top" class="index" onload="initialize()">
<!-- Header -->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
            <a href="index.html">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">
                    <h3></h3></div>
            </a>
            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="link" action="results.html">
                    <table>
                        <col width="1000">
                        <col width="500">
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <h3 style="border-bottom: 2px solid white;"> Tell us about your move! </h3><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Please enter your pick up address</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="start" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="85 Madeup Street, City, Zip Code, State" name="start"><img src="img/powered-by-google-on-non-white.png"/><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Please enter your drop off address</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="destination" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="64 Madeup Street, City, Zip Code, State" name="dest"><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Which type of vehicle will you need?</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="mode" class="form-control" name="mode">>
                                        <option value="#" selected>Type of Vehicle</option>
                                        <option value="VAN">Van</option>
                                        <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
                                        <option value="TRUCK">Pick Up Truck</option>
                                        <option value="CAR">Car</option>
                                    </select><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <h3 style="border-bottom: 2px solid white;"> Enter Contact Information </h3><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Please let us know your name</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=" e.g. John Johnson" name="name"><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Please enter your phone number. We will notify you when your driver is on their way</h4> <br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder=" e.g. 781222777"><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Please provide your email</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder=" e.g. example@example.com"><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <div class="col-sm-11">
                                <td>
                                    <h4> Could you please describe the items you are moving and the quantity?</h4><br>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <textarea id="description" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder=" e.g. 1 large couch, 2 small lamps, and a fruit bowl."></textarea><br>
                                </td>
                            </div>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4></h4><br>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="help" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                    <option value="Yes" selected>Yes Please!</option>
                                    <option value="No" selected>No Thank You</option>
                                </select><br>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="submit" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl" color="black" id="submit" onclick="saveData()">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

And also the Javascript

```
// USES THE GOOGLE PLACES LIBRARY
// ==============================
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autoCompleteOrigin, autoCompleteDest;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autoCompleteOrigin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('start')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  autoCompleteDest = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('destination')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autoCompleteOrigin, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autoCompleteDest, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine when I turned it into a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xiondark2008/4m4f1pq9/. The only possible "gotcha" I found was this not in the Google Docs you linked: "Note: The CSS classes described below are part of the experimental version of the Google Maps JavaScript API. Changes made to the experimental version are not guaranteed to be feature stable. For more information, see Versioning." So are you using the experimental build version?

Comment: Hmm...interesting. It could be the default CSS I'm using that's affecting the font then, though I don't see how this could be possible because I have no CSS attributes similar to the API Autocomplete attributes. I'm certain that I'm not using the experimental build.

Comment: In the JSFiddle, I AM using the experimental build since the documentation note said it was required. However, I just tried it using the latest build ("/js?v=3&....") and the css classes still worked. If this helps, it looks like Google creates a div with the class of "pac-container" outside of the header element. The result of the autocomplete menu are divs and spans.

Comment: @XionDark OK so I played around with the CSS files I have and found that my bootstrap CSS file is affecting the autocomplete, but what exactly is the issue? And what in bootstrap is affecting the text? [Bootstrap CSS Gist](https://gist.github.com/FreddieV4/31ef5b664d746e55a82c) I don't know what's going on with it

Comment: I noticed that the css you link sets the font size of span elements to 50px (which seems to match your screen shot). Is your CSS defined after you include the Bootstrap library?

Comment: @XionDark Yes. I modified it and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I had to go into the bootstrap css and change `span { font-size: 50px; }` to `span { font-size: 12px; }`